# Is it Possible to Add css to embedded Html Page?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML struccture like this:

```
<iframe>
#document
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
</iframe>
```

I want to modify the `css` of the embedded html page. Is there a way for the same? I am using React JS and tried to import additional css for the specific html but it remained unaffected.

Comment: have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Comment: This doesn't make it clear that for example I have a html tag within an iframe (or an id):
`#insideiframe013 {background-color: red;}`. How do I add this style to my css?